# Label element width till the end

Tags: html, css

I have searched for it. But unable to solve my problem.

I want the `label` element to grow till the end of the parent element so that when I get more space to select the radio. When I add `display: inline-block;` and `width: 100%;`, it goes in the next line.

```css
.q-option{
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
}
.q-option:hover{
}
label{
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 100%; */
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-option">
  <input type="radio" class="q-check" name="option" value="1" id="opt1">
  <label for="opt1">Preprocessor Home Page</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Definetly, If you go with width: 100%, it will go to next line. Because radio button symbol also need space.

You can achieve with the same html stucture by using position: absolute on child and position:realtive on parent with overflow: hidden.

There are other ways also like using flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on the parent and simply ensure that your label grows and shrink as necessary to fill up the remaining space.

You can optionally add a `gap` property to ensure there is sufficient negative whitespace between the actual radio button and the label itself:

```css
.q-option {
  /* Use flexbox on parent */
  display: flex;
  
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: red;
  
  /* Optional */
  gap: 8px;
}

.q-option:hover {}

label {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  
  /* Ensure label takes up remaining width */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-option">
  <input type="radio" class="q-check" name="option" value="1" id="opt1">
  <label for="opt1">Preprocessor Home Page</label>
</div>
```

### Even better: wrap your `<input>` with `<label>` directly

However, what I'd suggest is you make the entire radio button wrapped by the label element: in that way you do not have to provide an `id` and `for` attribute:

```css
.q-option {
  /* Use flexbox on parent */
  display: flex;
  
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  
  /* Optional */
  gap: 8px;
}

.q-option:hover {}

input + span {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  
  /* Ensure label takes up remaining width */
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<label class="q-option">
  <input type="radio" class="q-check" name="option" value="1">
  <span>Preprocessor Home Page</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe this could be a solution with flex:

```
.q-option{
    margin: 1px 0;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
}

label{
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```